# What's the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection equivalent to Autofac's lambda registration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

With Autofac we can register a dependency using a lambda registration, as follows:

```cs
builder.Register(c => GetCommandContext()).As<IAppDbContext>();
```

I want achieve the same with the built-in ASP.NET Core DI container.

This is what I tried:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IAppQuerier, AppQuerier>();  // this is standard registration

services.AddScoped<IAppDbContext, GetCommandContext()>(); // This doesn't compile

private IAppDbContext GetCommandContext()
{
    //for example
    var appDbContext = Substitute.For<ICommandsContext>();
    var roundOccurrences = AppTestsData.GetRoundOccurrences();
    appDbContext.RoundOccurrences.Returns(roundOccurrences);

    return appDbContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the factory delegate

```
services.AddScoped<IAppDbContext>(sp => GetCommandContext());
```

The `sp` is an instance of `IServiceProvider`